# What would be the past tense of bear into mind?

Tags: idioms

How would I use this idiom in this sentence- The memory of the incident has forever ........ into my mind?

Comment: As @BrianDonovan has pointed out in his answer, the correct idiom with "bear" in "bear in mind" , not "into" , and the subject is the owner of the mind. You are making an _effort_ to remember it. If you want to use "into", as for some idea that you can't forget, no matter how much you might want to, there are other idioms , such as _"The memory of the incident has **been forever etched** into my mind."_

Answer (score 1):

I fear you are confusing the verb in the idiom *to **[bear](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bear)*** [something] *in mind,* of which verb the past tense is *bore* (past participle *borne,* though [this site](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/irregular-verbs/bear.html) also allows *born),* with the  verb *to bore* meaning *to drill,* i.e. to cut a circular hole with a rotating tool.

> Idioms
>   35.
>   **bear /keep in mind,** to remember:
>   *Bear in mind that the newspaper account may be in error.* [[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bear--in--mind)]

The image of drilling into a mind suggests the ancient surgical procedure of trepanning, though in idiomatic use *[to trepan](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trepan)* more often suggests the extraction of secrets than forcible indoctrination.

You might alternatively be thinking of a different idiom or metaphor, where particularly vivid and thus memorable impressions are said to be *burned* into the mind. (I am not sure whether that is a metaphor from wood-burning, as a graphic technique, or from etching. Is Locke’s metaphoric *tabula rasa* made of wood or copper?) Nowadays this last idiom is often replaced with the observation that “you can’t unsee” something.